# onesignal in visual studio 2015

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, ionic-framework, onesignal

I'm trying to use onesignal in a mobile application for windows phone but i can't reach to make it works.

1. I created an example App with ionic :

   ionic start testAppWithOneSignal blank
2. I created my App on [Windows dev center](https://dev.windows.com/overview?from=UHF)
3. On [onesignal.com](https://onesignal.com/) my App is configured for Windows Phone 8.1+
4. In Visual studio, SDK is installed and appears in references for my App
5. Package.appxmanifest settings are ok (Toast capable : yes , capabilities : "Internet client & server"
6. My App is associated with windows store

When i launch my App on a windows phone, it works but when i add this code, my App crash when it goes in :

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.init("XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    {googleProjectNumber: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"},
    function(){console.log('oneSignal OK')});
```

Here the details of my configuration :

- Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
- Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.11
- Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
- Visual studio : Community edition 2015
- Windows 10

Comment: Please post your error message stack

Comment: Because it's an extarnal lib, i have no stack trace to explian the problem. I tried to open visual studio with "DevEnv.exe /log" but there is no explicit message in logs

Comment: But there should be any errors in your output or javascript console?!

Answer (score 0):

To get a stack trace of the crash you can try changing the Debugger Type to "Script Only" or "Managed Only" under the properties of the WP8.1 project.

[image: VS debug setting]

There is also a OneSignal-Ionic-Example project you can try to determine if the crash is from your project or if it is another issue. Make sure you're using the WP8.1 branch of the project.
https://github.com/one-signal/OneSignal-Ionic-Example/tree/WP8.1